# JavaFX task waiting for another task to finish

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I'm pretty new with concurency and I'v hit the wall several times already.
Code pretty much describes everything, but just to clarify: user press the button, application send query to db and in the meantime `statusLabel` is set to: 
Veryfing. 
200ms 
Veryfing.. 
200ms 
Veryfing... 
200ms 
Result of query

I'v managed to achieve that, but now, I need to use result of query in another class (if it succeed, another window is opened), but It never does. I came to conclusion that it just checks the result before Task is finished so result is always false, I have no idea how to work around this, so another class checks condition once Task is done.

First, my `Authorization` class

```
public class Authorization {
    private static String query = "";
    private static boolean isValid;
    private static Task<Void> task;

    public static void verifyLogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException{
        Status.get().unbind();
        isValid = false;
        task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws SQLException {
               while(!isCancelled()) {
                   try {
                       updateMessage("Weryfikacja.");
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                       updateMessage("Weryfikacja..");
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                       updateMessage("Weryfikacja...");
                       Thread.sleep(200);

                       if(username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                           task.cancel();
                           updateMessage("Pola nie mogą być puste");
                       } else {
                           query = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = ?";
                           Query.execute(query, username);
                           if(!Query.resultSet.next()) {
                               task.cancel();
                               updateMessage("Nie ma takiego użytkownika");
                           } else {
                               query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = ?";
                               Query.execute(query, username);
                               if(Query.resultSet.next()) {
                                   String passwordValue = Query.resultSet.getString(1);
                                   if(!password.equals(passwordValue)) {
                                       task.cancel();
                                       updateMessage("Podane hasło jest błędne");
                                   } else {
                                       task.cancel();
                                       updateMessage("");
                                       isValid = true;
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                       if(isCancelled()) {
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
               return null;
            }
        };
        Status.get().bind(task.messageProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

called from another class

```
  private void login() {
        if( SqlConnection.isConnected()) {
            try{
                Authorization.verifyLogin(String.valueOf(loginInput.getText()), String.valueOf(passwordInput.getText()));
                if(Authorization.isValid()) {
                    //should go to next menu
                    //but never does
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Debug.log(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

edit#
Sorry for polish in `updateMessage()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - waiting for task to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217442/javafx-waiting-for-task-to-finish)

Comment: The code is pretty confusing. What is the purpose of the `while` loop in the task? It looks like you call `cancel()` in the first iteration of the loop, under every possible condition, so why have the loop at all? Anyway, your `verifyLogin()` method simply starts the verification process in another thread, and then exits immediately. The `isValid` flag will not be changed until that thread completes, which happens quite a lot later. If you want to do the verification process and then do something else, it doesn't really make sense to manage the threads in `verifyLogin()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `verifyLogin()` method simply starts the verification process in another thread, and then exits immediately. The `isValid` flag will not be changed until that thread completes, which happens quite a lot later. If you want to do the verification process and then do something else, it doesn't really make sense to manage the threads in `verifyLogin()`.

I don't really understand a lot of what your code is supposed to be doing; you have a `while(...)` loop, which as far as I can tell can only be executed once (so is redundant). You also seem to execute two SQL queries which are essentially the same. (The first checks to see if there is a row with a certain condition, then if there is, the second retrieves that row. Why not just retrieve the row and check if it is there?)

I would refactor this so that the `validateLogin()` method doesn't handle the threading at all, and just returns the result of the validation (e.g. a status string, but maybe something else would be appropriate).

```
/**
  * @return An empty string if the login is valid, or an error message otherwise
  */

public static String verifyLogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException{
   isValid = false ;
   if(username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
       return "Pola nie mogą być puste";
   } 
   query = "SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login = ?";
   Query.execute(query, username);
   if(!Query.resultSet.next()) {
       return "Nie ma takiego użytkownika";
   } 

   String passwordValue = Query.resultSet.getString(2);
   if(!password.equals(passwordValue)) {
       return "Podane hasło jest błędne" ;
   } 


   isValid = true;
   return "" ;

}
```

Now I would manage the threads from the `login()` method. That way you can use the task's `onSucceeded` handler to execute code when the task completes:

```
private void login() {
    if( SqlConnection.isConnected()) {
        Task<String> verifyTask = new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws SQLException {

                return Authorization.verifyLogin(loginInput.getText(), passwordInput.getText());
            }
        };

        // probably better to use a progress indicator or similar here, but:

        Animation animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> Status.get().set("Weryfikacja.")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), e -> Status.get().set("Weryfikacja..")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(400), e -> Status.get().set("Weryfikacja...")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(600)));
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);


        verifyTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            animation.stop();
            Status.get().set(verifyTask.getValue());
            if(Authorization.isValid()) { // or if (verifyTask.getValue().isEmpty()) 
                // go to next menu
            }
        });

        verifyTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
            animation.stop();
            verifyTask.getException().printStackTrace();
            Debug.log(verifyTask.getException().toString());
        }

        animation.play();
        new Thread(verifyTask()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that is indeed working, but I actually managed to get to that point before, without using threads. The reason I started to use it is because I wanted to get "waiting effect". There are several situations like quering database or openning connections where program freeze for a brief moment. I thought Ill just add "animated" dots after status then so once user clicks something that freeze program, he see current status like "Connecting." -> "Connecting.." -> "Connecting...", etc, instead of program freeze. Not sure how to get those "dots floating" while program is waiting for some data

Comment: @user9309329 If you don't use threads, the UI will be completely unresponsive while the process is running (no other controls will work, the UI can't be repainted, etc.). That is not true here. You can, e.g. start an animation or display a progress indicator immediately before starting the thread and stop/remove it in the `onSucceeded`, for example.

Comment: Well my previous approach without threads had no progress indicators at all, once I decided to add them, I realized I need threads to make this work, but then I got a bit lost in this field as I never used them before. So basicly, I would need another task starting before `verifyTask` that updates my `statusLabel` as I wish, and stops once `verifyTask' is completed?

Comment: @user9309329 Added animation code in there. There is no need to use a thread to create an animation. Again, you could simply use a progress indicator instead of writing this yourself.